# Primeng styles not working in Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng

I am trying to use the `PrimeNg` components in my Angular 4 code. The modules are getting imported correctly but the styles are not getting applied.

Browser console is showing `404 error`.

I have used angular-cli to get the project boilerplate.

I have included the styles using link tag in index.html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link href="/node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css" />
```

I have added the stylsheet references to the "styles" property in angular-cli.json like this:

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css"
  ],
```

I have downloaded the required packages via NPM also and integrated them to the `package.json` file.

Comment: Are you sure that pathes in angular-cli.json correct?

Comment: confirm css file exist whatever path you specified into cli?

Comment: are you using webpack in your project ? and may i know primeng version used in your project ?

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all for responding with possible solutions.

I found the solution accidentally.

I am a newbie to Angular 4 so I did not know that after installing a new package via npm, you have to restart the server.

When I restarted my webpack, the app was working fine and the PrimeNg was also working fine.